# Double, float and long declaration

Tags: java, floating-point

I would like to know why in Java it gives a compilation error by doing the following operations:

```
double d34324.34; //error
float f3342.34; //error
```

On the other hand:

```
long L32423424; // works fine
double D32432424; // works fine
```

So basically I would like to know why there is this limitation with the syntax use only for floating point values.

I am aware that if the letter identifier (D,d,F,f) is put at the end of the number it works, but still I would like to know why the other form does not work with floating points.
Just curiosity, I know if I type 3443.43434f it works.

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined.

Comment: `double d = 1.3; float f = 1.3f;`

Comment: Because it parses "L32423424" as the NAME of the variable, not its value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
double d34324.34
```

doesn't assign a value of `34324.34` but tries to declare a variable with the invalid name `d4324.34` .

You probably wanted

```
double myDouble = 34324.34d;
long myLong = 34324l;
```

Comment: Well deserved -5 point for my question. Yep you are right, it was a trick of a book for a SCJP exam and I fell in the trap. I must have been for too long in front of the screen. #freshAir

Comment: Looked like that, that why I thought it was a real question, even if not the most enlightened one ;)

Answer (score 8):

A dot is not a valid character for an identifier (a variable name, a method name, a class name, a parameter name, etc.) It's right in section [§3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) of the Java Language Specification. So this will never work:

```
double d34324.34;  // error
float f3342.34;    // error
```

A valid identifier in Java can only contain letters, numbers, "_" and "$", and it must not start with a number. Notice that this excludes dots.

And why would you want to name a variable with a number? are you sure you didn't mean something like this, instead?:

```
double d = 34324.34;
float  f = 3342.34f;
```

Comment: You miss 'f' in float, it should be like: float  f = 3342.34f; unless you want to cast double to float as double is default when using literal with decimal point: float  f = (float) 3342.34;

Answer (score 2):

This is because it's an invalid variable declaration (syntax error) - can only have letters, digits, and underscores; and cannot start w/ a number

See this to learn about the [valid variable names in java](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/08.html)

> Variable names can include any alphabetic character or digit and the
>   underscore _. The main restriction on the names you can give your
>   variables is that they cannot contain any white space. You cannot
>   begin a variable name with a number.

Answer (score 0):

If the Value is whether flot or double to identigy the JVM using the number end with -d and -f. For example

```
0.04f(float) and 0.045d(double)
```

I think . is the root cause for the error.
Thanks